# Как с помощью JS изменить псевдоэлемент before или after

Tags: javascript, css

Например есть

```
   #tool:before{
        content:'';
        display: none;
        /* и т.д. */
     }
```

Как с помощью JS сделать display: block этому псевдоэлементу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, по моему никак. Как вариант это использовать несколько css файлов одинакового содержания, либо добавить на страницу блок `<style></style>`, а также к нему написать генератор нужных стилей. Да, костыль.

Comment: Зачем два одинаковых файла, когда можно сделать разные классы или иды, и плясать от них.

Answer (score 9):

вот так можно и без костылей вроде....

```js
var tool = document.getElementById('tool');

tool.addEventListener('click', () => {
  tool.classList.toggle('tool');
})
```

```css
#tool {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 25px;
}

#tool:after {
  content: 'Я псевдо-элемент after';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0ff;
}

#tool.tool:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 25px;
  background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="tool"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Современный вариант (если позволяет поддержка браузеров) - использовать css-переменные.
Если количество вариантов ограничено, то можно менять заранее заготовленные классы.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var color = "#" + (Math.random() * 0x1000000 | 0x1000000).toString(16).slice(-6)
  document.querySelector("p").style.setProperty('--sq-color', color)
})
```

```css
p {
  --sq-color: blue;
}

p::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: var(--sq-color);
}
```

```html
<p>Псевдоэлемент: </p>
<button>Перекрасить</button>
```

Comment: `Math.random() * 0x1000000 | 0x1000000` — если тут оставить только Math.random(), кажется тоже работает безошибочно.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, оказывается, в большинстве случаев да: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIx0w.png. Но мне как-то целое число из нужного количества цифр нравится куда больше.

Answer (score 2):

```
#tool:before{
    content:'';
    display: none;
    /* и т.д. */
}

.block:before{
     display: block;
}
```

Ну а в JS найти этот ваш #tool и добавить ему класс .block не поможет?

Answer (score 2):

Может кому понадобится!
Можно получить данные из псевдоэлементов after/before

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#tool'),':before').content;

var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#tool'),':after').getPropertyValue('content');
```

Answer (score 1):

Менять никак, а вот добавить элементы после или перед можно. Так и обходиться!

Answer (score 1):

Псевдоэлементы на то и псевдо, что метод .css('') к ним применить не получится. Только добавлять/удалять класс, который и будет определять стиль для :after/:before