# тег в псевдоэлементе ::after

Tags: css, веб-программирование, css3, вёрстка

Добрый день. Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: мне нужно поместить кнопку в псевдоэлемент. Что-то типа такого: `content: '<button>Нажать</button>'`. Как сделать это правильно?

Comment: такое возможно только с использованием javascript, `:after` не может вставить тег, больше о псевдоэлементах - http://css.yoksel.ru/content/

Comment: Насколько я знаю - никак. Кроме того, клик на псевдоэлементе невозможен.

Comment: Во-первых ни как.... А во-вторых, к чему такие страсти..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копай в сторону:
http://mattweb.ru/moj-blog/javascript-jquery/item/101-izmenyaem-psevdoelement-after-s-pomoschiyu-jquery
https://toster.ru/q/72270
[Как с помощью JS изменить псевдоэлемент before или after](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/162933/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-js-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-before-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-after)
В двух словах, изменить after - никак нельзя, все вышеизложеное - костыли по типу подмены класса или добавление еще 1 елемента и т.д. Твоя кнопка работать не будет никак :)

Answer (score -1):

Клик на псевдоэлементе не работает.
Поэтому упрятать туда кнопку - можно, но абсолютно без толку.

Comment: Саша Вдодович, если не жалко времени, поделись опытом как можно ` упрятать туда кнопку `...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/content...